# Как выбрать url изображений из файла?

Tags: регулярные-выражения, grep

Есть mysql-дамп из в котором есть ссылки на изображения, например `<img style=\"float: left;\" src=\"http://www.vademec.ru/upload/iblock/1d7/1d77389882672a4d7952dc80ae229d3f.jpg\"` , т.е. с экранированными `"` из которого нужно выбрать url картинок

```
grep -e "/<img(?:\\s[^<>]*?)?\\bsrc\\s*=\\s*(?|"([^"]*)"|\'([^\']*)\'|([^<>\'"\\s]*))[^<>]*>/" file.sql
```

Но `bash: ошибка синтаксиса около неожиданной лексемы ('`

Кроме того, в некоторых случаях после расширения есть дополнительные символы `name.png&677dnfnwf` и т.д.

Comment: Этот крокодил не совсем зеленый, как зовут собаку ?  ваш вопрос выглядит примерно так. Определитесь где и что вы хотите поменять. Ошибка в grep связана с двойными кавычками, которые у вас внутри строки и вы их не экранируете. Но какое отношение это  имеет к неким "командам MySQL" (в MySQL вообще нет комад, только запросы) не ясно

Comment: grep -e "/<img(?:\\s[^<>]*?)?\\bsrc\\s*=\\s*(?|/"([^/"]*)/"|\'([^\']*)\'|([^<>\'/"\\s]*))[^<>]*>/"

Такая конструкция не помогает. 

    grep -e "/<img(?:\\s[^<>]*?)?\\bsrc\\s*=\\s*(?|\042([^\042]*)\042|\'([^\']*)\'|([^<>\'\042\\s]*))[^<>]*>/"

Такая ничего не выдает.

Comment: А вы уверены, что после имени картинки может стоять амперсанд и еще какой то текст ? По стандартам амперсанд не является каким то спец-символом разделителем и если он есть то он входит в имя файла. Вот если бы после имени стоял вопросительный знак - тогда другое дело - это были бы параметры ... И вы констатировали факт, что эти символы могут быть после имени но не сказали, что делать если они есть

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Из вопроса сложно понять чего именно вы хотите добиться, но если вы имели виду, что на выходе grep должны быть только URL изображений, то выглядеть это должно так:

```
grep -ioP "<img[^>]+src=(\\\\?['\"])?\K.*?(?=([?].*)?(?(1)\1|[ >]))"
```

Ключи `grep`: `i` без учета регистра, `o` оставить только само совпадение, а не строку ее содержащее, `P` использовать диалект perl регулярных выражений.
Само выражение читается так:

```
<img          # <img
[^>]+         # любые символы кроме закрывающего тег (1 и более шт.)
src=          # src=
(\\\\?['\"])  # группа1: возможно обратная косая (приходится учетверять, т.к. выражение в двойных кавычках)
              # и одинарная или двойная кавычка
?             # группа1 может отсутствовать             
\K            # с этой точки начинается выдаваемая часть выражения
.*?           # любые символы (не жадный захват)
(?=           # после которых идет ... (не захватывающая проверка)
   ([?].*)?   # возможно вопросительный знак и часть которую надо отбросить
   (?(1)      # Условие: если группа1 присутствовала
        \1    #  то такие же символы как были в группе1, т.е. такая же кавычка как была
       |[ >]) #  иначе (кавычек на было) пробел или конец тега
)
```

Comment: Вырезает всю часть до url, но оставляет после расширения, хотя нужно удалить.

Comment: @Magi Я не вижу в вашем вопросе ни слова про то, что надо удалять что то после расширения и не вижу адекватного примера входных и выходных данных, охватывающего все возможные ситуации (только не говорите что вот то `name.png&677dnfnwf` это адекватный пример, ибо все что после амперсанда в этой строке по стандартам является частью имени файла !).

Comment: Мне казалось это очевидным. Все, что после расширения не нужно.

Comment: @Magi А как определить где расширение, если строка url у вас не соответствует стандартам и любой web-сервер по такой строке url файл никогда не найдет, потому как то же не знает где расширение. по стандартам  определяет конец имени файла только по наличию там знаков `?` или `#`, но в вашем примере нет таких знаков, поэтому я продолжаю утверждать, что указанные вами символы относятся к имени файла и отделять их нельзя

Comment: @Magi и если вам надо отделять от url что то стандартное, то приведите все таки правильные примеры url которые встречаются. Если что то нестандартное, то то же приведите и укажите как именно надо трактовать строку. Хотя такие доработки можете сами внести в регулярку по своему вкусу

Comment: Поискал в файле, больше такого примера не попадалось. Обычно как-то так .png?139151405913551

Comment: @Magi обработку параметров запроса (`?`) дописал. если хотите еще что то вырезать - доработайте сами, там надо только указать символы которые считать концом имени файла